# How to use the same route for creation and edition and navigate from one to another without destroying and creating the component again?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an angular application in which I use the same component to create and update objects of my database. From the list of registers (under `complaints`) I can navigate to an existing record (under `complaints/detail/id`) or to create a new one (under `complaints/detail`). When I create a new register, I'd like to remain in the same component (so it's not destroyed and created anew and the user doesn't see any flash) but the URL should be updated to reflect the Id of the new created item (from `complaints/detail` to `complaints/detail/id`).

How should I specify the routes in my module and how can I navigate from the creation page to the edition page?

Answer (score 0):

My [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atc93i).

In the route, only point to the component once to avoid recreation:

```
{
    path: 'data',
    redirectTo: 'data/'
},
{
    path: 'data/:id',
    component: CreateAndEditComponent
}
```

And in the component watch for parameter changes:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init');
    const getParams = () => {
      const dataId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      this.data = dataId.length > 0 ? this.getDataById(dataId) : new Data();
    };
    this.router.events.pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed)).subscribe(event => {
      // only listen for NavigationEnd as that indicates navigation processing is complete
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // get params for each consecutive route
        getParams();
      }
    });
    // get params for initial route
    getParams();
  }

  save() {
    this.service.saveData(this.data);
    this.router.navigate(['/data', this.data.id]);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't work for me because the component (your `create-and-edit.component`) is destroyed and created again after saving a new register. I need to perform some transitions when going from creation to edition and I can't do that if the component is destroyed and created.

Comment: If by "transitions" you're talking about animations, yes you can. Those are called router animations, but that's a separate question. But what you're after should be easy enough as well. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Freddy, in the end I've solved it just by adding the ID in the URL using the `history.pushState()` function from JavaScript.